# Android Studio: Scroll Vertical cuando se superponga el teclado

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una vista con varias `EditText` colocados verticalmente.
Al abrirse el teclado cuando selecciono un campo oculta los campos que hay a continuación del que he seleccionado. Para poder seleccionar los siguientes campos tengo que cerrar el teclado, seleccinarlo, escribir y volver a cerrar para pasar al siguiente campo.
¿Como se puede poner un Scroll vertical para que la vista de la actividad la pueda desplazar sin tener que cerrar el teclado.?

Comment: Vas bien, agregar un scroll siempre es buena idea cuando tienes multiples entradas de texto. Intenta agregarlo, si se te complica comparte el codigo de lo que intentaste y te ayudaremos a hacerlo andar.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la parte del código que tengo en el layout para el `ScrollView`.

````
<ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="594dp">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
               android:orientation="vertical">

               <!-- CAMPO CODIGO -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco1"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpCodigoTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="código tienda"
                       android:inputType="number" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- CAMPO NOMBRE -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco2"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpNombreTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="nombre de la tienda" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- CAMPO RED -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco3"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   android:digits="0123456789."
                   android:inputType="number"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpRedTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="dirección de red"/>
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- CAMPO MASCARA -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco4"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpMascaraTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="mascara de red" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- CAMPO BROADCAST -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco5"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpBroadcastTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="dirección de broadcast" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- CAMPO GATEWAY -->
               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/marco6"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/cmpGatewayTienda"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:hint="dirección puerta de enlace" />
               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <!-- TEXTO PARA MENSAJES DE ERROR -->
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                   android:textColor="#EF5350"
                   android:textSize="18sp" />

               <!-- BOTON MODIFICAR DE TIENDA -->
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/btnModificar"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/boton_verde"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                   android:text="Modificar"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

               <!-- BOTON BORRAR TIENDA -->
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/btnBorrar"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/boton_rojo"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                   android:text="Borrar"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:textColor="#E53935" />

           </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>```
````